# Combined searches and filters with a Matrix

Tags: matrix, search, filter, category

I am fairly new to Craft but have managed to build a combined search feature that users can filter from dropdowns. I used this as a guide and it works great:
https://webstoemp.com/blog/combined-searches-and-filters-craft-cms/ implemented here (still rough but working): http://resources.sttrcancer.org/resources-connect

I am now building out another search feature for an additional section ('members') but members has a MatrixBlock called ('position'), which contains a category field ('institution'). I am struggle with getting the institution list to show in my dropdown. I understand it is nested within the MatrixBlock and I am obviously missing a part of the syntax. Here is my working category dropdown that does not included the nested category:

```
{# get all entries to display only the categories related to entries #}
{% set memberAllEntries = craft.entries.section('member').limit(null).find() %}  

{# disease categories #}
{% set memberDisease = craft.categories.group('disease').relatedTo(memberAllEntries).order('title asc').find() %}

<div class="dropdown filter-button-container">

    <a href="#" class=" dropdown-toggle filter-button"  data-toggle="dropdown">Disease<span class="caret"></span></a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu"">
        {% for category in memberDisease %}

            {% set diseaseCategory = craft.request.getParam('disease') %}
            {% set diseaseActive = (diseaseCategory == category.slug) ? 'selected' : '' %}

            <li><label for="disease"/><input type="checkbox" class="cbxDisease" value="{{ category.slug }}" {{ diseaseTypeActive }}>&nbsp;{{ category.title }}</label></li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

I think I need on additional set command before here: `{% set memberDisease = craft.categories.group('disease').relatedTo(memberAllEntries).order('title asc').find() %}` to first select the matrix, then the previous code should select the 'institution' field within it. I have tried everything, I would LOVE any suggestions.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by removing .relatedTo(memberAllEntries) from the institution filter. My guess is being nested in the ('position') matrix the ('institution') category was not strictly .relatedTo any section.